# Photoshop - Merge all layers into a smart object or flattened layer to apply final Camera Raw filter

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

In some tutorial videos where they composite the scene using various images, effects, shading etc.(in separate layers). And at the end, they would try to apply `Camera Raw Filter`. But they would do it to a merged version, means all layers would be merged into a smart object or a flattened image.

How can I merge all my layers like that? Here's a screenshot of what am talking about: https://prnt.sc/w3g7xf

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Highlight the layers in the Layers Panel
- Right-click them in the Layers Panel
- Choose `Convert to Smart Object` from the popup contextual menu.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I have 3 layers and if I do this, then the three layers disappears and only the smart object layer appears. When I double click the smart object layer, I can see the 3 layers. But if you check the screenshot I sent, you could see that there are other grouped layers still visible. So how is that possible? If you like to have a look at what am saying, please check this url: https://youtu.be/M9QeYhPPcyE?t=1146 (it will jump to the correct time). Sorry if this is a dumb question, but eager to see what really is happening.

Comment: He's merely editing the Smart Object then saving/closing it and going back to the main document.

Comment: ah okay. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was looking for. To create a merged version of the visible layers, create a blank layer at the very top of all your other layers. Select this blank layer, and then press:

**Ctrl/Cmd + Alt + Shift + E**

This will create a merged snapshot version of your work.